# Cross-platform library in VS2013 and XCode

Tags: c, visual-studio, cross-platform

What's the best way to create from scratch a cross-platform C library?

The platform-independent code isn't my problem, it's almost already written. It's rather the IDE-integration and building/compilation part I'm unable to wrap my head around (VS at most).

Having one header file exposing the functions.
Having another `c`-File for each platform to implement the platform-specific stuff, using `#ifdef`-guards to prevent other platforms from compiling the non-relevant part.

I successfully managed to create an XCode project and compile it on Mac OS X (`xy.h` and `xy.macos.c`).

I've already added `xy.win32.c`. What's the easiest way now to import this into Visual Studio and just make it compile?

Is it considered good practice to have all these files in one place (`.sln` and `.vcproj` along with `.xcodeproj`) ? If not, what's the commonly used structure?

For Linux, this shouldn't be any problem as I'm quite familiar on the CLI using `make` and `gcc`.

Note: There are no other dependencies except the OS-specific function calls.

Comment: Try [configure scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Comment: Really? Is that the only solution? What do I need Visual Studio for then?

Comment: I never said that was the only solution, don't twist my words. It was merely a suggestion. As to Visual Studio: you don't *need* it. Many people write code without an IDE (myself included).

Comment: Sorry I did not mean to twist your words - it sounded more rude than it should have. I was somewhat surprised by your answer, that's all. Okay, although it is a solution, this is not the way I would like to go. Thank you anyway